# Concatenating files with Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Im new to using Gulp.  I'm trying to concatenate my JavaScript files into a single file. Currently, I have the following:

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var input = {
    js: './src/**/*.js'
};

var output = {
    js: './dist/myJavaScript.min.js'
}

gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'bundle-js']);

gulp.task('clean', function(callback) {

});

gulp.task('bundle-js', function() {
    gulp.src(input.js)
        .pipe(concat(output.js))
        .pipe(uglify())
    ;
});
```

When I run this, `myJavaScript.min.js` never gets generated. I ran `gulp --verbose` and I do not see any files being input. However, my directory structure looks like this:

```
/
  /src
    /childDirectory
      file2.js
    file1.js
  gulpfile.js
  package.json
```

Based on my understanding, the expression I used for `input.js` should get file1.js and file2.js. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give

1. file name inside concat function, you should not give it as a path name
2. add return before including source.
3. add destination

try the following code,

```
gulp.task('bundle-js', function() {
    return gulp.src(input.js)
        .pipe(concat('myJavaScript.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your destination folder.

[gulp-concat-link](https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-concat)

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('folderPathHere'));
```